# How do I make the labels invisible?

Tags: visualforce, jquery

Here is a very simplified version of a visual force page that I have created. This page displays two fields from the opportunity object. I am attempting to hide a few fields from this page. My idea is to use the classname for this purpose.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.JQuery210}"/>
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Opportunity</h1>
      <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opp Info" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField styleClass="readwrite" id="ReadWrite" value="{!Opportunity.X42Id__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="readonly" id="ReadOnly" value="{!Opportunity.X42Id__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField styleClass="readwrite" id="NameReadWrite" value="{!Opportunity.Name}" required="false"/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="readonly" id="NameReadOnly" value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
      var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
      j$(document).ready(function()
      {
        j$('.readwrite').css("display","none");
      })
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

This is hiding the fields, but the issue is that it is not hiding the labels created on the page.

[image: VF is hiding the fields, but not the labels next to them.]

Answer (score 1):

The way the HTML gets constructed in a inputfield may be causing this issue.
[image]
Since you already are using Jquery try using the `closet()` method and identify the closest table row and hide the tr of the td. There could be a better way to handle this but this works for sure, hence posting it as one of the solutions.

Try this :

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.JQuery210}"/>
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Opportunity</h1>
      <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opp Info" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField styleClass="readwrite" id="ReadWrite" value="{!Opportunity.X42Id__c}" required="false"/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="readonly" id="ReadOnly" value="{!Opportunity.X42Id__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField styleClass="readwrite" id="NameReadWrite" value="{!Opportunity.Name}" required="false"/>
                <apex:outputText styleClass="readonly" id="NameReadOnly" value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
        <script>
          var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
          j$(document).ready(function()
          {
            j$('.readwrite').closest("tr").hide();
            // or j$('.readwrite').closest("tr").css("display","none");
          })
        </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is the code that has worked for me.
```jQuery("label[for='" + jQuery("[id$='ReadWrite']").attr('id') + "']").hide();```